# Element shaking on Hover/Class Toggle only in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, transition

I have a sidebar menu with logo toggle button which toggles the class "toggled" and on large screens also appears on hover.
The sidebar is left: 100% and on toggle/hover left: 0;
On all browsers except safari it works fine. Only on safari the logo button wiggles/shakes when letting the navigation appear.

Here a short overview of the code:

```
.main-navigation {
//Structure
display: inline-block;
width: 160px;
transition: all 250ms ease-in;
height: 100vh;
z-index: 100;
position: fixed;
left: -100%; 
background-color: $color__primary;

&.toggled {
    left: 0;
}

.menu-toggle {
    margin-left: auto;
    align-self: flex-end;
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    left: 20px;
    top: 25px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 110;

    &:focus, &:active {
        outline: none;
    }
}
}
```

And on large screens i just add the hover:

```
.main-navigation{
    &:hover {
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

You can see it live under https://rocket.creos.agency/

I hope im just overlooking something small.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix your problem you need to move your 'logo' from the `nav` element. If it is inside, like you have it's trying too animate all elements inside `nav`.

Here is your logic with simple code (logo is inside `nav`):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 160px;
  left: -160px;
  background-color: tomato;
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}
nav:hover {
  left: 0;
}
button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
.content {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <button>
    Hover me
  </button>
  <div class='content'>
    <ul>
      <li>
        one
      </li>
      <li>
        two
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

And this is when 'logo' is outside the `nav`:

```js
(() => {
 const btn = document.getElementById('animateNav');
  const nav = document.getElementById('navigation');
  const content = document.getElementById('content');
  btn.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {   
    nav.classList.add("animate");
  });
  nav.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {   
    nav.classList.remove("animate");
  });
  nav.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {   
    nav.classList.add("animate");
  });
  content.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {   
    nav.classList.add("animate");
  });
})();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 160px;
  left: -160px;
  background-color: tomato;
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}
nav.animate {
  left: 0;
}
button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
#content {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<nav id='navigation'>
  <div id='content'>
    <ul>
      <li>
        one
      </li>
      <li>
        two
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<button id='animateNav'>
  Hover me
</button>
```

All difference is in second example that you need to toggle a class for `nav` using JavaScript. I provided not efficient logic to toggle a class, but I just wanted to present to you working solution.

P.S. don't use `<a>` tag inside of `<button>` tag

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer! Helps a lot.
And will keep the p.s in mind :)